# How to make a function that wait some conditions?

Tags: c#

Newbie to C#, learning in class to make windows forms. Here i found myself againts a situation. I have a few buttons, wich activate and deactivate under specific conditions. Is there a way to create a function wich wait for a variable to get some specific value to actvate? For exemple whenever `bool` get true, the buttons activate, and whenever it get false, they deactivate. I would like some help, or some tuto to learn from (looked for some, but didnt found what i look for).

Comment: It sounds like using a property instead of a variable would be the way to go.  A property has the chance to run code (such as enabling buttons) any time any other code writes to it.  Now you know what keyword to use when looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer because the other answerers make it look like either very hard or not possible.
This is quite easy using a c# feature called property. Properties are syntactic sugar for getter and setter methods surrounding a field.

In your case, you want something like this:

```
private bool _isActive;

public bool IsActive
{
    get { return _isActive; }
    set 
    {
        _isActive = value;

        if (value) // if the value assigned is true
        {
            someButton.IsEnabled = true; // enable a button, for example
        }
    }
}
```

You can then, use it like this:

```
public void SomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsActive = true;
}
```

Comment: Your buttons will never deactivate

Comment: @MickyD It's just an example, I'm aware of that. The point was to show properties

Comment: Do you have some references where i can learn more about this? Thanx for the answer

Comment: @AmineFellous Sure, the Microsoft Docs website has a lot of very good documentation when it comes to c#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to go about it.

The more advanced one is using ChangeNotification via the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface. This one is heavily used in WPF/UWP under the MVVM pattern.

However any Command pattern can work as well. Commands are abstractions. A command can be associated with a Hotkey Combination, a Button, a Menu Item, a Gesture (like Flipping yoru mobile phone) or all of those at the same time.

The ICommand Interface defines a "canExecute" and "Execute" Function. You need to regulary poll the canExecute to update the button states. But regular can go down as low as "60 times per second" or "only if you explicitly call for a update". However it is somewhat rarely used, as it was defined for the Deprecated Windows RT runtime.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, given that the OP is just starting learning programming, to show the most basic, OOP oriented example, with a property? This, as is, is most likely going to confuse the OP rather than help them

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanx for saying this for me ^^

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I consider the ChangeNotificaiton route potentially harder. Without supporting classes like WPF's Binding class it certainly is harder. And as a beginner he might not yet be aware how to properly seperate logic and UI. INotifyPropertyChanged is definitely the superior way, but superior might not be better in this case.

Comment: I didn't mean the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which IMO is overkill for this, I meant just a property

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Oh right, I had totally forgotten that Option. I guess a case of being blind to the obvious solution

Answer (score -1):

At your stage, the best solution for you would be something like below:

```
if(FunctionWhichHasSomeCondition(SomeVariables)
{

if conditions met, activate or deactivate button.
}


..

public bool FunctionWhichHasSomeCondition(somevariable)
{
//Some conditions to be met. if met return true else return false.
}
```

Comment: Im gonna try the normal way. But i was really curios. You have function wich wait for X condition (click, text change, etc) to run. Make me wonder if it was possible to do the same with a variable.

Comment: This is the same as the now deleted answer by @faring. This code executes once while the OP asks for a solution for this to run automatically or under some event